# Why do we need a matrix to plot 3D graphs in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, plot

I was studying MATLAB and found this code for plotting a 3d graph

```
x=-8:0.1:8
y=x
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y)
R=sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2)+eps
Z=sin(R)./R
mesh(x,y,Z,'-')
```

Being confused about the use of the `meshgrid` function, I decided to try to avoid it and instead wrote

```
x=-8:0.1:8
y=x
r=sqrt(x.^2+y.^2)+eps
z=sin(r)./r
mesh(x,y,z)
```

and to my surprise, it showed an error as

```
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector
```

Now, as far as I understand, to draw a 3d graph, you only need to mark the points `(x,y,z)` accordingly as the values are given (in case of 2d, that's what it does). To do that, it only needs a list of values for `x`, `y` and `z`. So, what exactly is the problem with having `z` as a list? I would prefer a detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html#d123e839387) where you found that example, the usage is given:
<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

> `mesh(X,Y,Z)` creates a mesh plot, which is a three-dimensional surface that has solid edge colors and no face colors. The function plots the values in **matrix** `Z` as heights above a grid in the x-y plane defined by `X` and `Y`. The edge colors vary according to the heights specified by `Z`.

The example you referred to is this:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:.5:8);
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;
mesh(X,Y,Z)
```

The documentation for [`meshgrid()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) says:

> `[X,Y] = meshgrid(x)` is the same as `[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,x)`, returning square grid coordinates with grid size `length(x)`-by-`length(x)`.

Okay, what is `meshgrid(x, x)` doing?

> `[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y)` returns 2-D grid coordinates based on the coordinates contained in vectors `x` and `y`. `X` is a *matrix where each row is a copy of `x`*, and `Y` is a matrix where *each column* is a copy of `y`. The grid represented by the coordinates `X` and `Y` has `length(y)` rows and `length(x)` columns.

This is pretty self-explanatory, right? When you do `[X, Y] = meshgrid(-8:2:8)`, for example, you get this:
<sup>I reduced the density of points to help clarify what's happening</sup>

```
X =

  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   8
  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   8
  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   8
  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   8
  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   8
  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   8
  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   8
  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   8
  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   8

Y =

  -8  -8  -8  -8  -8  -8  -8  -8  -8
  -6  -6  -6  -6  -6  -6  -6  -6  -6
  -4  -4  -4  -4  -4  -4  -4  -4  -4
  -2  -2  -2  -2  -2  -2  -2  -2  -2
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8
```

If you plot every point given by `x = X(i, j)` and `y = Y(i, j)` for all `i` and `j`, you'll get something like this:

[image: x-y plot of meshgrid output]

When you do the next lines:

```
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps;
Z = sin(R) ./ R;
```

you are doing matrix math and `R` and `Z` are matrices just like `X` and `Y`. The element `Z(i, j)` gives you the value of your `z` axis at `x = X(i, j)` and `y = Y(i, j)`.

However, when you run *your* code, `x`, `y` and `z` are vectors. If you plot  all pairs of `x` and `y`(again I reduced the density of points), you get the red points -- a diagonal line, instead of the mesh you actually need.

[image: x-y plot of your code]

`mesh()` *needs* your points to be on a mesh (because that's what it does -- create a *mesh* plot). Your code only provides the `z` values of the points on the diagonal line `x = y`.

Plotting the matrices gives a surface / mesh plot:
[image: mesh plot]

If you only want a 3D line plot, check out the `plot3()` function.

`plot3(x, y, z)` gives:

[image: plot3 plot]

Comment: Nice! I just tried using `plot3` instead of `mesh` in the program (that does not have the `meshgrid` command), and it worked! Now, I understand the difference. Thanks!

Comment: This is a brilliant answer actually!

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful. If I may offer a tip for beginner coders: Don't hesitate to read the docs and try it out. The matlab command window is amazing for this reason: it's a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), so you can try different things and see what they do in real-time. Reducing the size of your problem and then printing what you're doing is immensely helpful when you're trying to get an intuitive understanding of what your code is doing @SayanDutta